# Can we have Api methods in an Api class in backend

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am new in backend programming of android. Usually i make one API method in an API. I am curious if we can have two API methods in a class. I searched on google but i didn't get any answer.
For example its my code with one API method

```
  @Api(name = "InformationAPI",
            version = "v1",
            namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "backend.labs.com", ownerName = "backend.labs.com", packagePath = ""))
    public class EntryEndpoint {

        @ApiMethod(name = "addEntry")
        public Result addEntry(
                @Named("Name") String name,

        ) throws SQLException {

            Connection conn = getConnection();
            Result result = new Result();
            Boolean opsFlag;
            try {
                opsFlag = executeInsertQuery(conn, name);
                result.setIsSuccess(opsFlag);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean? Elaborate your question

Comment: i had edited my question. And sorry i am not familiar with some terminologies of android. so please help me to frame my question more appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

For futher on Libraries check : https://packetzoom.com/blog/which-android-http-library-to-use.html

For further on Examples : https://github.com/traex/RetrofitExample